# Why am I getting `list index out of range` error?

Tags: python, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I wrote a code to download the synonyms of the words in a list, `locations`. But since a word can have multiple meanings, I used another list, `meaning`, to point to the serial number of the meaning I want for that word. Then calculate similarities between the words based on these synonyms found, and then save them in a file.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from textblob import Word
from textblob.wordnet import Synset

locations = ['access', 'airport', 'amenity', 'area', 'atm', 'barrier', 'bay', 'bench', 'boundary', 'bridge', 'building', 'bus', 'cafe', 'car', 'coast', 'continue', 'created', 'defibrillator', 'drinking', 'embankment', 'entrance', 'ferry', 'foot', 'fountain', 'fuel', 'gate', 'golf', 'gps', 'grave', 'highway', 'horse', 'hospital', 'house', 'land', 'layer', 'leisure', 'man', 'market', 'marketplace', 'height', 'name', 'natural', 'exit', 'way', 'park', 'parking', 'place', 'worship', 'playground', 'police', 'station', 'post', 'mail', 'power', 'private', 'public', 'railway', 'ref', 'residential', 'restaurant', 'road', 'route', 'school', 'shelter', 'shop', 'source', 'sport', 'toilet', 'tourism', 'unknown', 'vehicle', 'vending', 'machine', 'village', 'wall', 'waste', 'waterway'];

meaning = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

ncols = len(locations)
nrows = len(locations)
matrix = [[0] * ncols for i in range(nrows)]

for i in range(0,len(locations)):
    word1 = Word(locations[i])
    SS1 = word1.synsets[meaning[i]]
    for j in range(0,len(locations)):
        word2 = Word(locations[j])
        SS2 = word1.synsets[meaning[j]]
        matrix[i][j] = SS1.path_similarity(SS2)

f = open('Similarities.csv', 'w')
print(matrix, file=f)
```

But the code gives the following error:

```
SS2 = word1.synsets[meaning[j]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I printed out the values of `i` and `j`, I found that it prints till i=0 and j=36. That means that when j=36, the error arises. The word in the list at index 36 is `man`, and the value at index 36 of `meaning` is 11.

[image]

So, why is this error occuring and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:** The mistake was in `SS2 = word1.synsets[meaning[j]]`. It should have been `SS2 = word2.synsets[meaning[j]]`. Sorry.

Comment: What is the output of `print(word1.synsets)`?

Comment: It seems `word1.synsets` doess not have as many as the number of items in `locations`.

Comment: @TomWyllie It prints 13 different meanings of the word `man`. I have included the screenshot in the question now.

Comment: @JoséSánchez `word1.synsets` contains 13 things, and I want to extract he 11th one. I have included the screenshot in the question now.

Comment: Why `SS2 = word1.synsets[meaning[j]]` instead of `SS2 = word2.synsets[meaning[j]]`. You did not use `word2` in your code really.

Comment: @yixiao Damn! That was the error. Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`len(word1.synsets)` returns 8 and `type(word1.synsets)` returns list.  So it's a list with indexes 0 to 7.

your list 'meaning' contains 11 at index 36.  so when your loop reaches `word1.synsets[11]` you get the index out of range error.

Like Jose said, 7 is the max int you can have in 'meaning'.

Comment: `len(word1.synsets)` returns 13 for me (I have edited the question to include the the screenshot in the question).